# Prevent order go to processing status if condition is true

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, global-variables, orders

I tried many scenarios and hooks and at the end even in child template file for thankyou page

So if order is not failed and global variable == true switch to pending:

```
<?php if ($order->has_status('failed')) : ?>

//code

<?php else : ?>

<?php if ($GLOBALS['variable'] == true) : ?>


    <?php $order->update_status('pending'); ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Status is changing but the problem is that it is going from processing to pending. How to prevent going to processing status if condition ($GLOBALS['variable']) is true?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the supplied details.

Comment: @mickmackusa so status is set to "pending" and is not "processing" before that?

Comment: This should really not be done by writing code into arbitrary places, but by using an appropriate _hook_.

Comment: @CBroe like I said in poust I tried many hooks, so I must write all hooks that I tried (woocommerce_order_status_change and combinations from https://gist.github.com/abegit/74e691d877cadc37d7b6)? I have posted question after testing. There are many hooks and always I have problem with not changing status and with no errors in log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following for Cash on delivery (COD) payment method, replacing in the code both `'my_variable'` with the correct slug:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'conditionally_change_cod_order_status_to_pending', 10, 2 );
function conditionally_change_cod_order_status_to_pending( $status, $order ) {
    $global_var = $GLOBALS; 

    if ( isset($global_var['my_variable']) && $global_var['my_variable'] ) {
        return 'pending';
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer! .. but problem stays, even if I change priority to 20: "Order status changed from In Processing to Payment in progress." goal is that not come to "processing" status...

Comment: @alench Is this for a specific(s) payment method (like credit card payments)?

Comment: no, Cash on delivery ...

Comment: @alench I have updated my answer code… Now it should work as you expect.

Comment: is working- thanks! "Pending" was an example, I needed this hook for custom status which is also working.